How to change behavior of classic ASP.NET Iframe control's Save icon (button)
I'm using the iframe control from .NET 4.0 for now:
<iframe runat="server" id="iframepdf" width="900" height="1100" 
        src="RenderImage.ashx"></iframe>

When I load the frame with a PDF, it works great with the .ashx file.
However, the control has a "Save" icon at the top right for saving, but when I click on it, it wants to name the output as RenderImage.ashx with file type .ashx. Once I change the name to any PDF filename, it works fine, but I just wonder if there's a way to correct the "Save" feature. If I could tell the control to save as {whatever}.pdf, that would be groovy.
If not, that's okay. I also have a button for downloading. Just thought I'd ask!

You will just need to add headers appropriately in your RenderImage.ashx
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext filecontext)
{
    filecontext.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

    // Set the Content-Disposition header to suggest a filename
    filecontext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=FILENAME.pdf");

    // Retrieve and write the PDF file content to the response
    byte[] pdfContent = GetPdfContent();
    filecontext.Response.OutputStream.Write(pdfContent, 0, pdfContent.Length);
    filecontext.Response.Flush();
    filecontext.Response.End();
}

private byte[] GetPdfContent()
{
   File.ReadAllBytes(context.Server.MapPath("~/path/to/your/FILENAME.pdf"));
}

